# DrupalVM unable to change PHP version

Tags: php, windows, drupal, vagrant

When I changed the default PHP version to 5.4.43 in config.yml it is ignored and the site remains at PHP 7. I need 5.4.43 because that's what my live site uses at bluehost. I need to mirror my live site exactly on my local computer to find a subtle bug.

How to fix this?

Comment: I may have found the reason I'm having difficulty. There is a comment in the config.yml that reads "PHP Configuration. Currently-supported versions: 5.6, 7.0." I guess that means PHP 5.4.43 is not an option. The next obvious question is how can I configure Vagrant/DrupalVM with PHP 5.4.43?

Comment: Given that your live host uses 5.4 and your VM supports 5.6, you should be able to get by with using 5.6 locally.  There are a few differences in *configuration and features*, but syntactically they are nearly identical.  Since 5.6 is backwards compatible with 5.4, anything that runs on your hosting service will run on your local machine.  You would just have to avoid using features locally that aren't available in 5.4.

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to email your hosting provider and ask them to update PHP to 5.6.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I was in error when I said I needed 5.4.43. I actually need 5.6.17. I have since discovered that Vagrant/DrupalVM can be configured with 5.6.17, but I need to do more reading & research to find out how this is done.

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 with Vagrant/DrupalVM. I'm trying to mirror the versions of the various server components locally to track down a mysterious Drupal bug. Please see https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/838#issuecomment-236455445 for more information.